# HTTP result code tags

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Thanks to Lucas Kauffman's wikitag activity I've noticed a number of HTTP return code tags like [404](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/404), [402](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/402), [302](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/302), [303](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/303), [500](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/500) and probably a whole number of others. They seem to be at least ambiguous to me, if not entirely useless.

Any objections to stripping the tags from affected questions and asking for a block to prevent future use?

#### Edit

I've started re-tagging and suddenly found myself wading knee-deep in serious shit. There are [301-redirect](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/301-redirect) (81 questions), [301](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/301) (20 questions), [403](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/403) (61 questions), [404](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/404) (121 questions), [http-status-code-404](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-404)(21 questions), [500-error](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/500-error) (80 questions), [500](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/500) (12 questions), [502-error](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/502-error) (11 questions), [502](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/502) (5 questions), [503-error](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/503-error) (36 questions), [504](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/504) (7 questions).

Just removing the tags from all the affected questions should be safe, but doing it "by hand" is tedious and would pop around 450 questions to the front page. Is this something to ask the devs?

#### What has been cleared so far and can be blocked:

[302](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/302)
[302-permanent-redirect](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/302-permanent-redirect)
[401](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/401)

Comment: Entirely useless, and also [too-localized]

Comment: Useless yes but too localised? These codes are used globally by any even half-decent web server. How much more non-localised can you get?

Comment: Would [tag:http-303] be more useful as a tag than just [tag:303]?

Comment: @Ladadadada There also exists [http-status-code-404](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-404), [http-status-code-403](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-403) and [http-status-code](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code). Thoughts?

Comment: If these were the only tag on a question, it would be ruled off-topic or useless; burnination time.

Comment: I would argue that a status/response code of whatever kind is a bad candidate as a crouping criterion, thus making it a bad tag. so http-status-code-whatever would also need retagging IMO.

Comment: The tags for 404 and http-status-code-404 need to be cleaned up. I would go with 404. Right now, there are questions with one or both those tags. I'll manually clean, just tell me your preference. 403 should remain, as it is important (403 is Forbidden) in my opinion.