# Merge 500 and 500-error and rename

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I see that we have a [http-status-code-403](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-403) tag. It is quite clear what 403 is referring to in that tag name.

We do not have a [http-status-code-500](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-500) tag. Instead we have [500](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/500) and [500-error](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/500-error), which are both very unclear names. All the questions I saw in those tags so far were about HTTP status code 500.

Any reason not to merge both of those tags into a new [http-status-code-500](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/http-status-code-500) tag?

(As far as I can tell it requires a moderator to actually do it.)

Comment: Related: [HTTP result code tags](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3151/http-result-code-tags)